# Mount glusterfs on kubernetes hosts

Tags: kubernetes, glusterfs, kubespray

When mounting glusterfs on servers where kubernetes is installed via kubespray, an error occurs:

```
Mount failed. Please check the log file for more details.

[2020-12-20 11:40:42.845231] I [MSGID: 100030] [glusterfsd.c:2454:main] 0-/usr/sbin/glusterfs: Started running /usr/sbin/glusterfs version 3.8.8 (args: /usr/sbin/glusterfs --volfile-server=kube-pv01 --volfile-id=/replicated /mnt/replica/)
pending frames:
patchset: git://git.gluster.com/glusterfs.git
signal received: 11
time of crash: 
2020-12-20 11:40:42
configuration details:
argp 1
backtrace 1
dlfcn 1
libpthread 1
llistxattr 1
setfsid 1
spinlock 1
epoll.h 1
xattr.h 1
st_atim.tv_nsec 1
package-string: glusterfs 3.8.8
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libglusterfs.so.0(_gf_msg_backtrace_nomem+0x7e)[0x7f084d99337e]
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libglusterfs.so.0(gf_print_trace+0x334)[0x7f084d99cac4]
/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6(+0x33060)[0x7f084bfe2060]
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libglusterfs.so.0(gf_ports_reserved+0x13a)[0x7f084d99d12a]
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libglusterfs.so.0(gf_process_reserved_ports+0x8e)[0x7f084d99d35e]
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/glusterfs/3.8.8/rpc-transport/socket.so(+0xc09b)[0x7f08481ef09b]
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/glusterfs/3.8.8/rpc-transport/socket.so(client_bind+0x9d)[0x7f08481ef48d]
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/glusterfs/3.8.8/rpc-transport/socket.so(+0x98d3)[0x7f08481ec8d3]
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgfrpc.so.0(rpc_clnt_reconnect+0xc9)[0x7f084d75e0f9]
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgfrpc.so.0(rpc_clnt_start+0x39)[0x7f084d75e1c9]
/usr/sbin/glusterfs(glusterfs_mgmt_init+0x159)[0x5604fe77df79]
/usr/sbin/glusterfs(glusterfs_volumes_init+0x44)[0x5604fe778e94]
/usr/sbin/glusterfs(main+0x811)[0x5604fe7754b1]
/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6(__libc_start_main+0xf1)[0x7f084bfcf2e1]
/usr/sbin/glusterfs(_start+0x2a)[0x5604fe7755ea]
---------
```

[11:41:47] [root@kube01.unix.local ~ ]# lsb_release -a
Distributor ID: Debian
Description:    Debian GNU/Linux 9.12 (stretch)
Release:    9.12
Codename:   stretch

```
Repository revision: git://git.gluster.com/glusterfs.git
Copyright (c) 2006-2013 Red Hat, Inc. <http://www.redhat.com/>
```

On servers without kubespray is mounted successfully.
How do I fix this error?

Comment: `signal received: 11` refers to Segmentation Fault.  https://serverfault.com/a/67506/405997

Comment: 1) if you're in cloud environment and it's cheap to replace the machine, try to do this, might be hardware bug, 2) do main logs report any related errors (system log, dmesg, systemd)?

Comment: Thanks. Solved updated to Debian 10 (Buster)

Answer (score 1):

When mounting glusterfs on servers where kubernetes is installed via kubespray, an error occurs:

Solved. Update Debian 10